# Grails 3.1.0.M2 Database Reverse Engineering

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

Need of help.

I am new to Grails,

My question is How to do db-reverse-engineer.?

I did it in Grails 2.5.1 but I am struggling with Grails 3.1.0.M2 version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please mark the question as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no plugin for Grails 3. I started to convert the older one but it's more work than I was expecting because it has to work with Hibernate 4, and the old plugin only works with Hibernate 3.

But the generated files wouldn't be any different in Grails 3 than in Grails 2 since GORM has stayed rather consistent. Since the plugin is only used at build time, and often only once or at most a few times, I recommend that you configure a Grails 2 app with the same database config settings and using the plugin there, then moving the generated files to your Grails 3 app.

Comment: Thanks. My architect said same thing.