# How to install grails db-reverse-engineer

Tags: grails

Trying to use the Grails [db-reverse-engineer plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/db-reverse-engineer).  As this plugin [doesn't work with Grails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253688/grails-3-1-0-m2-database-reverse-engineering) I used [SDKMAN](http://sdkman.io/) to [install older versions](https://fbflex.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/managing-multiple-versions-of-grails-with-gvm/) of Grails just to generate the models.  First tried version 2.5.2 (which was still incompatible with [the tutorial](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-db-reverse-engineer/docs/manual/guide/single.html#4%20Tutorial)) and then spun back to 2.2.5.  Following the tutorial still fails to install the plugin:

```
$grails create-app reveng-test
| Created Grails Application at /home/user/pnvStuff/grails/reveng-test
$ cd reveng-test
$ grails install-plugin db-reverse-engineer
| Environment set to development.....
| Warning The install-plugin command is deprecated and may be removed from a future version of Grails.  Plugin dependencies should be expressed in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy.  See http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/conf.html#pluginDependencies.
| Error resolving plugin [name:db-reverse-engineer, group:org.grails.plugins, version:latest.integration]. Plugin not found.
| Error Plugin not found for name [db-reverse-engineer] and version [not specified]
```

I also tried installing the plugin by referencing it in the plugins section of the BuildConfig.groovy.

```
runtime ':db-reverse-engineer:0.5.1'
```

How can I get this plugin installed to generate the needed domain classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails 2.x (and 1.x for that matter) plugins are now in a repository that isn't included in `BuildConfig.groovy` by default. You need to add the below Maven repo to your dependency resolution block.

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    repositories {
        mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/"

        ...
```